# Is this sentence about specific people, or a certain type of people in general?

Tags: translation

In this sentence I have a problem of interpretation:

> 本来なら魔石やドロップアイテムは『サポーター』と呼ばれる非戦闘員が回収して確保してくれるんだけど、　『ヘスティア・ファミリア』の構成員は僕一人だけだから以下略
>
> “To be precise, the non-combatant who collects me and provides me the magic stones and released objects is called "support", but, being the only member of Hestia family [ ... ]”

For me it is not clear if the subject is talking about non-combatants in general or if he is talking about a specific non-combatant.

I think that he is referring to a specific one for two reasons: the first reason is because there is 本来なら (normally) and this is why I translated: "the non-combatant who collects..." and the second reason is because before the text there was this sentence:

> 魔石の欠片を腰巾着、【コボルトの爪】を背にしょっている黒色のバックパックに放り込む。

Comment: Please post one question at a time. You can edit this question leaving one problem and create separate questions for the other.

Comment: Hello,

previously in the text there was this sentence:
魔石の欠片を腰巾着、【コボルトの爪】を背にしょっている黒色のバックパックに放り込む。

This is a reason wky I think that in the sentence 本来なら魔石やドロツブアイテムは『サポーター』と呼ばれる非戦闘員が回収して確保してくれるんだけど、　『ヘスティア. ファミリア』の構成員は僕一人だけだから以下略 the speaker is referring to 魔石の欠片を腰巾着 and not to non-combatant in general. What do you think?

Thanks,
Nadia

Answer (score 3):

魔石の欠片を腰巾着、【コボルトの爪】を背にしょっている黒色のバックパックに放り込む。
I (pick up and) throw magic stones into my drawstring waist bag, and コボルトの爪 into my black backpack on my shoulders.

本来なら魔石やドロップアイテムは『サポーター』と呼ばれる非戦闘員が回収して確保してくれるんだけど、
Under normal circumstances (i.e. in other/normal Familias), magic stones and dropped items are (supposed to be) collected by non-combatants called "supporters", but...

『ヘスティア. ファミリア』の構成員は僕一人だけだから
I am the only member of "Hestia Familia", so...

以下略
The rest is omitted. (<- We have no supporters, so I have to collect the dropped items all by myself.)

Comment: So he is talking about 非戦闘員 called "supporters" in general.

Comment: @naruto そですね・・・